# "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'"

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get the JSON response from the server and send it to the console but it's returning the following error.

[image]

**Class BannerApi**

```
class BannerApi {
  String id;
  String nome;
  String bclass;
  List<BannerItemApi>? bannerItem;

  BannerApi({
    required this.id,
    required this.nome,
    required this.bclass,
    required this.bannerItem,
  });

  factory BannerApi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    inspect(json);
    return BannerApi(
      id: json['id'].toString(),
      nome: json['name'],
      bclass: json['class'],
      bannerItem: json['activeBannerItems'].length == 0
          ? null
          : List<BannerItemApi>.from(json['activeBannerItems'].forEach((x) {
              BannerItemApi.fromJson(x);
            })),
    );
  }
}
```

**Class BannerItemApi**

```
class BannerItemApi {
  String id;
  String titulo;
  String descricao;
  String imageUrl;

  BannerItemApi({
    required this.id,
    required this.titulo,
    required this.descricao,
    required this.imageUrl,
  });

  factory BannerItemApi.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    inspect(json);
    return BannerItemApi(
      id: json['item'][0]['id'].toString(),
      titulo: json['item'][0]['title'],
      descricao: json['item'][0]['text'],
      imageUrl: json['item'][0]['image'],
    );
  }
}
```

Server response does not return null at any time.

Inspect from **BannerItemApi.fromJson(x)**

[image]

Comment: Can you share your model as well ?

Comment: ok, i already edited the question

Comment: The model is incomplete still there should be model of BannerItemApi also

Comment: Sorry, I already put

Comment: are you getting error with List<BannerItemApi>? this?

Comment: Yes, if remove works

Comment: Okay now using ? this your code working fine right?

Comment: I don't understand , I get the error but if I comment out the line **List<BannerItemApi>.from(json['activeBannerItems'].forEach((x) {BannerItemApi.fromJson(x);}))** the error disappears

Comment: are you getting some value in json['activeBannerItems'] this?

Comment: yes it has value

Comment: Basically this happens when you are getting a null value from response and the variable that you are assign value is not nullable. If you still have doubt then please share a sample of json response that you are getting from server then I'll let you know exact reason.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
json['activeBannerItems'].length == 0
          ? null
          : List<BannerItemApi>.from(json['activeBannerItems'].forEach((x) {
              BannerItemApi.fromJson(x);
            })),
```

to

```
json['activeBannerItems'] == null
          ? null
          : (json['activeBannerItems'] as List)
              .map((i) => BannerItemApi.fromJson(i))
              .toList(),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bannerItem: json['activeBannerItems'].length == 0
          ? null:..
```

replace for

```
bannerItem: json['activeBannerItems'].length == 0
              ? [] ...
```

in bannerapi